# Ruby gsub IRB Error

Tags: ruby

I have trouble executing following command using IRB. Ruby 2.0
The script is taken from official Ruby Core 2.0 Doc.

```
"hello".gsub(%r([aeiou])/, '<\1>')

(irb):2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"hello".gsub(%r([aeiou]), '<\1>')
```

You have an additional `/`. Either use `%r()` or `//` as regexp delimiter.

I checked the documentation and I confirm there is a typo there. However, I believe it's caused by RDoc because [the original source is correct](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/string.c#L3979-L3983).

Comment: What is the difference between them?

Comment: There is no difference. Ruby lets you create a Regular Expression in different ways.

Answer (score 3):

```
"hello".gsub(%r([aeiou]), '<\1>')
"hello".gsub(/[aeiou]/, '<\1>')
```

Use `%r()` or `//`